# Uploading same App in two developer console Accounts

Tags: android, google-play

Suppose I have two developer console accounts.
If I want to upload same apk in both accounts, then whether both apps works fine and ad will serve properly or is there any problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't upload same .apk from two account or the same account.Google check out the packageName and version for this .So if you want to upload same .apk from two account the you have to change the package name

Answer (score 2):

Should work fine as long as the package name of both the apps are different.

Comment: no.. it will not get changed but YOU have to change it as Play Policy specifies that you need to have unique package name to upload an app.

Answer (score 0):

Play store requires each app to have a unique package-name to identify each app individually. ( Just like we are assigned unique roll numbers in exam :) )
Here is what you can do

1) You create a new project with same source code and change package-name. ( Easy way)
2) Create a new project. Add existing project as library to it. Create a dummy activity in new project which just calls you main activity. This way you will not have duplicate code.

But I will not advise that because then your app will be competing with itself. Your downloads will be divided between two independent app which will result in lower chance of your app to be discoverable.